# Directories searched by \input primitive

Tags: input

I use MacTeX 2019. The question is as follows: if a TeX source file says `\input <file name>`, where does TeX look for a file with the specified file name, and in what order?

Comment: The current working path, your `~/texmf`, the `texmf` folders in your installation (`/usr/local/texlive/2019` in Linux, guess the path is similar on MacTeX). You can check which file is used by running `kpsewhich <file name>` in the command line.

Comment: Type the command `kpsewhich --var-value TEXINPUTS` at a Terminal prompt, and you’ll get the answer you are looking for.  You must be able to understand the syntax of `texmf.cnf` configuration files, though… :-)